# Cross-platform QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield

I've been working with QGIS in Linux and Windows for some time now and I only now realised that there's an alternative for QGIS for Android and iOS.

Is there a way to save your project in Linux/Windows on a cloud drive, in such a way that you can open the project on your mobile device? I'm assuming the layer paths would be the main issue.

In my field of work it would be super beneficial to be able to open projects you've been working on, at your computer, on the mobile device as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use open-source [Mergin Maps](https://merginmaps.com), one of the officially recommended mobile apps by QGIS project. It got [mobile](https://github.com/MerginMaps/mobile) app and also [server](https://github.com/MerginMaps/server) for sharing the data.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the project

Comment: …and it works on iPhones as well… thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. QFieldCloud. There is a free community plan, which is only good for file based projects. It has a 100mb limit. No collaborators. Or a paid plan, which allows PostGIS based projects, and multiple users access.